# $S(X)\simeq S(Y) \Leftrightarrow X\simeq Y$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, affine-varieties

We know that if $X,Y$ are affine varieties with $A(X)\simeq A(Y)$, then they are isomorphic (where $A(X)$ is the coordinate ring of $X$).

I'm trying to verify if there is an analogous result for projective varieties, namely:

> If $X,Y$ are projective varieties with $S(X)\simeq S(Y)$, can we say $X\simeq Y$?

(where $S(X)$ is the homogeneous coordinate ring)

My first idea was to consider the affine cones $C(X), C(Y)$, whose coordinate rings are $S(X), S(Y)$. Then $S(X)\simeq S(Y)$ is equivalent to $C(X)\simeq C(Y)$.

Now I'm stuck because I don't know how to prove (or disprove) that $C(X)\simeq C(Y)\Leftrightarrow X\simeq Y$.

Comment: I would look at the [proj construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proj_construction).  I believe that the isomorphism of coordinate rings needs to be an isomorphism of graded rings.

Comment: Certainly an isomorphism of graded rings induces an isomorphism of projective varieties. However, abstractly isomorphic projective varieties need not correspond to an isomorphism of graded rings, i.e. $k[x,y]$ and $k[x,y,z]/(xz - y^2)$ both correspond to $\mathbb P^1$ (the latter as a smooth conic), but they are not isomorphic as rings. You might want to also look at the notion of "projective equivalence," which is an isomorphism between two subvarieties of the same projective space which is induced by an automorphism of that projective space (a linear change of coordinates).